# Error in Flutter Format Exception: Unexpected character (at character 1)

Tags: flutter, api, dart

Hello everyone i am new flutter and currently i am working on a project on debug mode when i am adding data into my app i got this error
Exception has occurred.

```
FormatException (FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
<!DOCTYPE html>
^
)
```

Please tell me any advice

Here is the code example

```
Future<AccademicCertModel> GetCert() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var token = pref.getString('token');

    var headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'};
    var request = http.Request(
        'GET', Uri.parse('$baseUrl/api/user/training-certificates/get'));

    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return AccademicCertModel.fromJson(
          jsonDecode(await response.stream.bytesToString()));
    } else {
      return AccademicCertModel.fromJson(
          jsonDecode(await response.stream.bytesToString()));
    }
  }
```

I got the error on this line  `jsonDecode(await response.stream.bytesToString()));`

Comment: Can you call api in postman and add response here as it looks like something wrong is there with json

Comment: body response is 200

Comment: Kindly add json response in question that you got  from postman

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the response returned in not JSON, but seems to be HTML.

You can print the value by doing something like:

```dart
  var body = await response.stream.bytesToString();

  print('body: $body');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return AccademicCertModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(body));
  } else {
    return AccademicCertModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(body));
  }
```

The `token` can be incorrect, or the server rejected the request for some reason.